# Azure DevOps Pipeline build agent: how to use or replace $(DevEnvDir) in assembly reference HintPath?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have Visual Studio 2019 Professional locally, Azure DevOps pipeline build agent has Enterprise.

How to reference the ReferenceAssemblies in the project file, that resolves both locally and in the build agent?

Projectfile: builds **locally**, but pipeline build fails because of wrong path:

```
<HintPath>$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
```

Projectfile: builds in **azure devops pipeline**, but local build fails because of wrong path:

```
<HintPath>$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
```

Projectfile: builds **locally**, but pipeline build fails, because $DevEnvDir is *Undefined*:

```
<HintPath>$(DevEnvDir)\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Condition`:

```
<Reference Include="Mono.Android.dll">
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional')">$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
    <HintPath Condition="Exists('$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise')">$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a pipeline variable called `DevEnvDir`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline

Comment: Thank you! Although **HintPath Condition** works in my case, the pipeline variable is more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with my visual studio 2019 enterprise, both `<HintPath>$(ProgramFiles)\....\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>` and `<HintPath>$(DevEnvDir)` work for me.

You can go to the folder specified in the hintpath to make sure that the mono.android.dll truly exists. You can also try manually locating the mono.android.dll.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not the missing file, but difference between devops build agent and local build environment.